# Adding characters to a two-dimentional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am really having a hard time trying to fill my two dimensional array in Javascript.

I have a different array with lots of letters that I want to add to my 'board' but even the board dose not seem to be working correctly. Whenever I try to print board to the web page using the draw Board method I get NaN for the place where the letter A is. The rest is displaying the number 0.

```
var ROW = 10;
var COLUMN = 10;
var board = [['A', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];

function drawBoard(board) {
    var str = '';
    for (var x = 0; x < ROW; x++){
        str += '<div class="row">';
        for (var y = 0; y < COLUMN; y++){
            str += '<div class="column">' +
            + board[x][y] + '</div>' + '</div>';
        }
        str += '</div>';
    }
    $('#board').append(str);
}

$(function(){
    drawBoard(board);
});
```

What I want to do is have this string:

```
var Letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M'];
```

make a for loop to just board[x][y] = Letters.pop(). And then display the board with the new letters.

Are there any better ways to add an array to a two dimentional array than just running two for loops?
Why dose my board display NaN and not the letter. I have tried many different things.

Comment: You might really use `<table>` elements - they are appropriate for this use case :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first question. If you look at your code:

```
       str += '<div class="column">' +
        + board[x][y] + '</div>' + '</div>';
```

you can see that you have a `+ +board[x][y]`, not a `+` when adding `board[x][y]`. The unary `+` tries to convert the value of `board[x][y]` to a number before concatenating giving you the `NaN` error( as @Bergi pointed out).

To add an element to the end of an array you can use the `push()` method (in your case`board.push(Letters)`). This will place the element, which can be an array, at the end of the array.

If you want to replace a line in the array you can use `board[x] = Letters`.

Comment: Well spotted, although actually it isn't `++`, but the unary `+` operator

Comment: You're right. Well spotted to you to. I'll update the answer.